# $product->ID in has_term() not working, but manually inputting the ID works, why?

Tags: taxonomy, terms, get-posts

I have this code which I am using to loop through all products, then it should print the `$current_product` array if a product has term 'composite' from the 'product_type' taxonomy - it doesn't.

**BUT** if I replace `$product->ID` in the `has_term` function with the actual number **it works fine and prints the array**. Why?!

```
public function test12() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    );

    $products = get_posts( $args ); ?>

    <?php foreach( $products as $product ) {

        if( has_term( 'composite', 'product_type', $product->ID ) ) {

            $current_product = array(
                'ID'            => $product->ID,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
            );

            echo 'has';

            print_r($current_product);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($product->ID);` ?

Comment: the var dump is: int(3833) where 3833 is the looped ID

Comment: I tested and worked fine. Where are you using this function? On a theme? Plugin?

Comment: After a WP All Import job using the action pmxi_after_xml_import

Comment: If `$product` is a `WP_Post` instance, you can pass that directly as 3rd argument to `has_term` rather than `$product->ID`.

Comment: Tried that but no change in the result.